# SQLSERVER 2017: select first occurrence of contiguous groups ordered by date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

This is hard to articulate.  I am on SQLSERVER 2017.  What I want to do is select the first occurrence of rows in a set based upon how they are grouped. However, these "groups" do repeat sometimes.  The grouping is the sponsor_dist_id, but the challenge for me is I can't just get the first occurrence of each sponsor_dist_id by date because that group repeats itself for another set of dates later on.  I need the first occurrence of that one also -- and so on. **Example:**

```
+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| dist_id | sponsor_dist_id |   it_beg_date    |   it_end_date    |
+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   76566 |           48584 | 10/13/2015 00:00 | 10/30/2015 00:00 |
|*  76566 |           48584 | 10/30/2015 00:00 | 11/28/2016 00:00 |
|*  76566 |           48584 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/28/2016 00:00 |
|   76566 |               4 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/28/2016 00:00 |
|   76566 |           48584 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/29/2016 00:00 |
|*  76566 |           48584 | 11/29/2016 00:00 | 11/28/2018 00:00 |
|*  76566 |           48584 | 11/28/2018 00:00 | 11/29/2018 00:00 |
|*  76566 |           48584 | 11/29/2018 00:00 | 11/30/2018 00:00 |
|   76566 |               4 | 11/30/2018 00:00 | NULL             |
+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

*To generate source

```
SELECT convert(numeric(20,0),dist_id) dist_id, convert(numeric(20,0),sponsor_dist_id) sponsor_dist_id, convert(datetime,it_beg_date) it_beg_date, convert(datetime, it_end_date) it_end_date 
INTO #tmp_GridResults_1
FROM (
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2015-10-13 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2015-10-30 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2015-10-30 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'4' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2016-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2016-11-29 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2016-11-29 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2018-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2018-11-28 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2018-11-29 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'48584' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2018-11-29 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], N'2018-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS [it_end_date] UNION ALL
SELECT N'76566' AS [dist_id], N'4' AS [sponsor_dist_id], N'2018-11-30 00:00:00.000' AS [it_beg_date], NULL AS [it_end_date] ) t;
SELECT [dist_id], [sponsor_dist_id], [it_beg_date], [it_end_date]
FROM #tmp_GridResults_1

DROP TABLE #tmp_GridResults_1
GO
```

**And what I want to achieve is as follows:**

```
+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
| dist_id | sponsor_dist_id |   it_beg_date    |   it_end_date    |
+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
|   76566 |           48584 | 10/13/2015 00:00 | 10/30/2015 00:00 |
|   76566 |               4 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/28/2016 00:00 |
|   76566 |           48584 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/29/2016 00:00 |
|   76566 |               4 | 11/28/2018 00:00 | NULL             |
+---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

So basically remove the rows that have an asterisk.  However, with that I now have rows where the start date and end dates have gaps.  So I need the dates to be contiguous (i.e. the start date from the next row should be the end date for the first row).  Hope that all makes sense.  Thanks!

**Example:**

```
  +---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
    | dist_id | sponsor_dist_id |   it_beg_date    |   it_end_date    |
    +---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
    |   76566 |           48584 | 10/13/2015 00:00 | 11/28/2016 00:00 |
    |   76566 |               4 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/28/2016 00:00 |
    |   76566 |           48584 | 11/28/2016 00:00 | 11/28/2018 00:00 |
    |   76566 |               4 | 11/28/2018 00:00 | NULL             |
    +---------+-----------------+------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: It would *really really* help if you posted the CREATE and INSERT commands instead of just the data. People now have to create the tables and type the data themselves to try and solve the problem

Comment: In any case, what you ask is a relatively typical `islands` problem. In SQL Server 2012 and later it can be solved using windowing functions like LEAD, LAG, DENSE_RANK etc

Comment: I added a script to generate the table and source data.  Hopefully I did that right.

Answer (score 0):

```
select dist_id, sponsor_dist_id, min(it_beg_date), max(it_end_date)
from....
where …
group by dist_id, sponsor_dist_id
order by dist_id, sponsor_dist_id
```

That should get you pretty close to it.

EDIT:
Changed the min(it_end_date) to max(it_end_date). Given the data you've supplied this will return your expected results, I think.

Comment: That's not what the question is about. The OP wants to identify the "islands" in the data. `GROUP BY` would eliminate them and return only a single row per "island"

Comment: yeah, thanks for trying, but that doesn't get it.  The "islands" in the data is a good way to describe what I am dealing with.